# Where should I get rpcuser.py from?

Tags: bitcoin.conf, rpc-error-25

I am following the instructions in my bitcoin.conf file, it writes:

```
It is set at intialization time
# using the output from the script in share/rpcuser/rpcuser.py after providing a username:
#
# ./share/rpcuser/rpcuser.py alice
```

However, I can't finde any rpcuser folder or rpcuser.py file. Am I supposed to have them? Is this normal? I already ran

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```

So, if I don't have the file, where should I get it from? Does this mean my bitcoin installation is incomplete? I havent synced all the blockchain yet..

Anyway, any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `rpcuser.py` script anymore, it is now named `rpcauth.py` (the ppa may not be up to date). This file can be found in the Bitcoin Core source code repository: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/share/rpcauth/rpcauth.py